# diagram with curved arrows and instructions (probably tikz)

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows

I'll just cut to the chase.  I'd like to do this:
[image]
I would think tikz is the thing to use, but I'm not sure how to make the curvy arrows.  Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest code for this case

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\node (a) at (-2,0) {probability};
\node[align=center] (b) at (2,0) {percent\\change};
\draw[-latex] (a) to[out=60,in=120] node[midway,font=\scriptsize,above] {multiply by 100\%} (b);
\draw[-latex] (b) to[out=-120,in=-60] node[midway,font=\scriptsize,below] {divide by 100\%} (a);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

These are the best ways IMO (with `\GREAT` (not `\great` or `\Great`) help from [Skillmon](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/117050/skillmon) and [marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/121799/marmot) in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/481935/156344))

Based on Skillmon's answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\node (a) at (-2,0) {probability};
\node[align=center] (b) at (2,0) {percent\\change};
\begin{scope}
\catcode`\%=12
\draw[-latex,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.5ex,text along path,text
align=center,text={|\scriptsize|multiply by 100%}}}] (a) to[out=60,in=120] (b);
\draw[latex-,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=.5ex,text along path,text
align=center,text={|\scriptsize|divide by 100%}}}] (a) to[out=-60,in=-120] (b);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Based on marmot's answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{bending,decorations.text}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\sffamily
\node (a) at (-2,0) {probability};
\node[align=center] (b) at (2,0) {percent\\change};
\draw[-latex,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=-1.5ex,text along path,text
align=center,text={|\scriptsize|multiply by 100{\%}}}}] (a) to[out=60,in=120] (b);
\draw[latex-,postaction={decorate,decoration={raise=.5ex,text along path,text
align=center,text={|\scriptsize|divide by 100{\%}}}}] (a) to[out=-60,in=-120] (b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both give

[image]

Comment: If you just load (without explicitly using it) the library `bending` the result will become even prettier because then the arrows are taken into account for the path construction.

Comment: @marmot Thanks! I am working on an improvement. Maybe I will add this to it.

Comment: But I need the code for "percent chance" not "percent change."  Haha just kidding.  Perfect!  Thanks!

Comment: @BenW Ohh what happened to my eyes :)