# Drawing a circular arrow diagram with multiline text nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

What would be the best way to create such a circular diagram with TikZ?

I found a few similar examples online that I tried to modify, but I always ended up having issues with the following:

- Can't use formatting nor add a newline in the text nodes
- No border around text nodes
- Clockwise arrows aren't circular

[image: Circular diagram draft]

Some examples tried, to no avail:

- [Simple way to make circular arrow arc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/511183/simple-way-to-make-circular-arrow-arc)
- [Diagram with curved arrows and instructions (probably tikz)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481925/diagram-with-curved-arrows-and-instructions-probably-tikz)
- [Drawing a diagram of a three-cycle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/287284/drawing-a-diagram-of-a-three-cycle)

Comment: I think this one is the best one for you: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287293/14757 You can insert line break inside nodes if you use some alignment, eg, `\node[align=center]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to do it automatically, so adapting [this link provided by Sigur in the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/287293/14757), you can do something like this:

[image: circular diagram with arrows]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, bending}

\begin{document}

    \tikzset{mynode/.style={text width=2.5cm, align=center}}
    
    \newcommand{\R}{4cm} % Circle radius
    \newcommand{\texta}{\textbf{Title 1} \\ Description 1}
    \newcommand{\textb}{\textbf{Title 2} \\ Description 2}
    \newcommand{\textc}{\textbf{Title 3} \\ Description 3}
    \newcommand{\textd}{\textbf{Title 4} \\ Description 4}
    \newcommand{\texte}{\textbf{Title 5} \\ Description 5}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[-{Stealth[bend]}]
        \foreach \a/\t in {90/\texta,18/\textb,-54/\textc,-126/\textd,-198/\texte}
        {
            \ifnum\a=90
                \node[mynode,yshift=-10pt] at (\a:\R) {{\t}};
            \else
                \node[mynode] at (\a:\R) {{\t}};
            \fi
            \draw (\a-15:\R)  arc (\a-15:\a-55:\R);
        } 
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

But you may found the placement a bit odd. So you need to do it manually.
Place the nodes (can be done with the loop) then draw the arrows by try and error.

[image: manual version]

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}[-{Stealth[bend]}]
        \foreach \a/\t in {90/\texta,18/\textb,-45/\textc,-135/\textd,-198/\texte}
            \node[mynode] at (\a:\R) {{\t}};
        
            \draw (70:\R) arc (70:30:\R);
            \draw (10:\R) arc (10:-35:\R);
            \draw (-55:\R) arc (-55:-125:\R);
            \draw (-145:\R) arc (-145:-190:\R);
            \draw (150:\R) arc (150:110:\R);            
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your example works perfectly for my needs. I did try to use the link given by Sigur, but got confused with the arrow placement. Your answer makes it way clearer.